# Accept Google Translate in my IPTABLES

Tags: linux, iptables, google

I want enable the `translate.google.com` IP.

My problem: The `translate.google.com` IP is changed frequently, see:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se].  **;-)** Please don't post screen shots of text but copy-paste the text instead and use code formatting to display it correctly: Ctrl+K or the { } button in the text field will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance.  Q upvoted. and if you change the screenshot to text, I'm pretty sure you won't attract any more downvotes (It's one of these things here...)  **;-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't change: they're load balanced for speed and reliability.

To get the ones for your Internet connection in your geographical area do a:

```
$ nslookup
> translate.google.com
Server:     m.n.o.p
Address:    m.n.o.p#53

Non-authoritative answer:
translate.google.com    canonical name = www3.l.google.com.
Name:   www3.l.google.com
Address: m.n.o.100
Name:   www3.l.google.com
Address: m.n.o.139
Name:   www3.l.google.com
Address: m.n.o.101
Name:   www3.l.google.com
Address: m.n.o.113
Name:   www3.l.google.com
Address: m.n.o.138
Name:   www3.l.google.com
Address: m.n.o.102
```

and add all of them.

<sub>**Note:** Using `m.n.o.(p)` to anonymize my specific connection.</sub>